# leafnode fetchnews: received bogus greeting (498)

Tags: command-line, networking, log, logging, administration

How do I run some sort of diagnostic to check the connection to an upstream [leafnode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leafnode) NNTP server running on the same network?

```
thufir@arrakis:~$ 
thufir@arrakis:~$ telnet 192.168.1.7 119
Trying 192.168.1.7...
Connected to 192.168.1.7.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
thufir@arrakis:~$
```

It connects for a second, then the connection is closed...I never typed in the escape characters.

Alternately, what can I look for on the server in terms of logs to see why it closed the connection?

The `news.err` and `news.notice` logs in `/var/logs/news` are empty on the upstream server `doge`.

The downstream server, `arrakis`, can connect to `NNTP` servers fine.  As can the upstream server, `doge`.  (These are just FQDN's registered on no-ip.com, not "real" domains.)

```
thufir@arrakis:~$ 
thufir@arrakis:~$ sudo fetchnews -vvv
leafnode 1.11.10: verbosity level is 3, debugmode is 0
try_lock(timeout=5), fqdn="arrakis.bounceme.net"
192.168.1.7: connecting to port nntp...
error: NNTP server went away (server disconnect or timeout)
error: 192.168.1.7: received bogus greeting (498): (nil)
192.168.1.7: address list exhausted without establishing connection.
192.168.1.7: connection failed.
news.mozilla.org: connecting to port nntp...
news.mozilla.org: connected to 216.166.97.169:119, reply: 200
news.mozilla.org: connected.
news.mozilla.org: using STAT <message-ID> command.
Not posting to news.mozilla.org: nopost-set 
news.mozilla.org: getting new newsgroups
^Cfetchnews: caught signal 2, shutting down.
WARNING: some servers have not been queried!
wrote active file with 156888 lines
Started process to update overview data in the background.
Network activity has finished.
thufir@arrakis:~$
```

Both `arrakis` and `doge` aren't headless servers, I use them as regular pc's.  On `doge` I'm able to connect to `localhost` fine with the `pan` newsreader.

However, connections from `arrakis` to `doge` aren't working either from `leafnode` using `fetchnews` nor `pan` or even `alpine`/`pine` e-mail client.

[Perhaps](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/news-with-leafnode/) it's a security issue:

> If you want to protect your Leafnode server by using TCP wrappers, you
>   can do so easily. If the news server is available only for intranet
>   use, you may want to seriously consider doing this so that your news
>   server can’t be abused by the outside world. Let's assume that your
>   internal network is using the IP network address of 192.168.1.0. You
>   would write the following in your /etc/hosts.deny file to allow only
>   machines with IP addresses located in your local network to access
>   Leafnode: leafnode: ALL EXCEPT 192.168.1. 127.0.0.1

It's a somewhat older system, not sure of the leafnode version:

```
thufir@arrakis:~$ 
thufir@arrakis:~$ sudo leafnode --version
200 Leafnode NNTP Daemon, version 1.11.10 running at arrakis.bounceme.net (my fqdn: arrakis.bounceme.net)

^Cthufir@arrakis:~$ 
thufir@arrakis:~$ 
thufir@arrakis:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=wily
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.10"
thufir@arrakis:~$
```

The downstream server, `arrakis`, has a news entry in `inetd`:

```
thufir@arrakis:~$ 
thufir@arrakis:~$ cat /etc/inetd.conf
# /etc/inetd.conf:  see inetd(8) for further informations.
#
# Internet superserver configuration database
#
#
# Lines starting with "#:LABEL:" or "#<off>#" should not
# be changed unless you know what you are doing!
#
# If you want to disable an entry so it isn't touched during
# package updates just comment it out with a single '#' character.
#
# Packages should modify this file by using update-inetd(8)
#
# <service_name> <sock_type> <proto> <flags> <user> <server_path> <args>
#
#:INTERNAL: Internal services
#discard        stream  tcp nowait  root    internal
#discard        dgram   udp wait    root    internal
#daytime        stream  tcp nowait  root    internal
#time       stream  tcp nowait  root    internal

#:STANDARD: These are standard services.

#:BSD: Shell, login, exec and talk are BSD protocols.

#:MAIL: Mail, news and uucp services.
nntp   stream  tcp     nowait  news    /usr/sbin/tcpd  /usr/sbin/leafnode

#:INFO: Info services

#:BOOT: TFTP service is provided primarily for booting.  Most sites
#       run this only on machines acting as "boot servers."

#:RPC: RPC based services

#:HAM-RADIO: amateur-radio services

#:OTHER: Other services

thufir@arrakis:~$
```

Comment: `fetchnews` brings no joy? Is this leafnode 1 or 2? And hi :)

Comment: @andrew.46 good call, but no luck.  however, more informative error!  Hi :)  not sure of the version, put in what info I have.

Comment: Hmmm... is there an entry in `/etc/inetd.conf`?

Comment: Hmmm... I am not sure, perhaps news.software.readers?

Comment: @andrew.46 see kludge below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

futzed around with `hosts.allow` and `hosts.deny` in a very insecure way:

```
thufir@arrakis:~$ 
thufir@arrakis:~$ cat /etc/hosts.allow 
# /etc/hosts.allow: list of hosts that are allowed to access the system.
#                   See the manual pages hosts_access(5) and hosts_options(5).
#
# Example:    ALL: LOCAL @some_netgroup
#             ALL: .foobar.edu EXCEPT terminalserver.foobar.edu
#
# If you're going to protect the portmapper use the name "rpcbind" for the
# daemon name. See rpcbind(8) and rpc.mountd(8) for further information.
#

#-- leafnode begin
leafnode: 192.168.1.7
leafnode: 127.0.0.1
#-- leafnode end
thufir@arrakis:~$ 
thufir@arrakis:~$ cat /etc/hosts.deny 
# /etc/hosts.deny: list of hosts that are _not_ allowed to access the system.
#                  See the manual pages hosts_access(5) and hosts_options(5).
#
# Example:    ALL: some.host.name, .some.domain
#             ALL EXCEPT in.fingerd: other.host.name, .other.domain
#
# If you're going to protect the portmapper use the name "rpcbind" for the
# daemon name. See rpcbind(8) and rpc.mountd(8) for further information.
#
# The PARANOID wildcard matches any host whose name does not match its
# address.
#
# You may wish to enable this to ensure any programs that don't
# validate looked up hostnames still leave understandable logs. In past
# versions of Debian this has been the default.
# ALL: PARANOID

#-- leafnode begin
#leafnode: ALL
#-- leafnode end
thufir@arrakis:~$
```

and ignored all the warnings in the fine manual per config file:

```
## By default, leafnode only serves connections from addresses in the
## local networks and drops those from outside. An IPv4 address, or an
## IPv6 address on computers that provide the getifaddrs() interface is
## considered local if it is within the networks (IP/netmask) of the local
## interfaces. On computers that lack the getifaddrs() interface, an
## IPv6 address is considered local if it is site-local, link-local or
## the loopback address (::1).
##
## You can enable remote access by doing:
## 1. enabling access for single static IPs (or subnetworks) through
##    your super server (xinetd, tcpserver) or, if the service is wrapped by
##    tcpd, hosts.allow/hosts.deny configuration,
## 2. disabling access for all other hosts (default to deny),
## 3. testing that "deny" works, to avoid abuse of your server,
## 4. uncommenting this option, capitalizing the "strangers" subword and
##    setting the value to 42.
##
## WARNING: ENABLING THIS OPTION IS DANGEROUS. YOU AGREE TO BE LIABLE
## FOR ALL ABUSE OF YOUR SERVER WHEN THIS OPTION IS ENABLED.
## IF ANYTHING ABOUT ITEMS 1. TO 3. ABOVE IS UNCLEAR, DO NOT ENABLE THIS!
## IF YOU ARE NOT FAMILIAR WITH ACCESS CONTROL, OR YOUR CLIENTS ARE ON
## DYNAMIC IPS, YOU MUST NOT ENABLE THIS. (You can use other, authenticated,
## methods of access instead, for instance SSH tunnels.)
##
#

allowSTRANGERS = 42
```

now, sorta, kinda works.  obviously, not a ***good*** solution.